# PHP function not returning TRUE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a function that will check if a user is subscribed or not, but the code doesn't work, it doesn't return `TRUE` even if the user is subscribed.

Here is an example of my code.

```
function is_subscribed($email)
{
    global $DBC;

    $result = mysqli_query($DBC,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($row['subscribed'] == 'yes') { 
                return TRUE; 
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}

$user_email = $_SESSION['email'];

if(is_subscribed($user_email)) {
    echo "YES!";
}
```

Comment: What comes out when doing `var_dump($row['subscribed']);` or `var_dump($row)`

Comment: Your query is invalid. `email` is a string. You should parameterize the query. Put an `else` and error report on `$result` and you'll see the issue.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Why? If they unsubscribed the OP might not want it to be true.

Comment: Also, why not just do it all in the query? `WHERE email = '$email' AND subcribed = 'yes'` then check `num_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap $email into quotes because it is a string.
So:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

Comment: hawkeye ;-)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

just do few change add sigle quote

```
$result = mysqli_query($DBC,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
```